# raspberry pi with NOOBS: crontab does nothing

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi with NOOBS. I am trying to run a script every 5 minutes with crontab. It is not working. So I made a test command and added it to my crontab file.

I typed "crontab -e"
then added "* * * * * date >> /Documents/crontab logs/crontab_test_log.txt"
My understanding is that this should get the date and time every minute then save it to a test log file. After rebooting the pi and waiting for 10s of minutes nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using the full path to `date` - you can find that by typing `which date`. And try enclosing the output filename in double quotes as it contains a space.

Comment: I tried this and still nothing happened. I thought cron jobs started automatically at boot up. my assumption must be wrong. How does one start a cron job. I know how to edit the crontab file but how do I actually make it run. Do I need to edit another config file or use a special command?

Comment: Do you have mail installed? If not try installing it (sudo apt-get install mailutils). The cron job will then mail you it's results so you can see what error you are getting.  Here is a reference for using the mail system: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/mail.htm

Comment: I installed mailutils and now I can see that crontab is sending me error messages through 'mail'. Thanks for your help!